# “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

while run iphone simulation, I show the error for "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in Xcode

code is below :

Test.h

```
 @interface Test : UIViewController
 {
   int iWeight;
 }

end
```

Test.m

```
@implementation Test

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   iWeight = 15; 
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    **NSLog(@"integer Number is :%@", iWeight);  // error occur**

}
```

If i click the Button of UIAlertView, Xcode occur "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error at that code

I don't know why that code occur error. help me.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that you passed a bad pointer somewhere.  You need to figure out which line of code is causing it, then figure out what you're doing to pass a bad pointer.  Passing an integer where a pointer is expected in a format method is one case, but there are many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `NSLog(@"integer Number is :%d", iWeight);`

Answer (score 0):

```
yes, try this

NSLog(@"wieght is %d",iweight);

%d type specifier for int iweight;

and also set property in .h file and synthesize it in .m file.

if it dont work then try this
remove your alertview method

write this


// .h file
-(IBAction)buttonClicked; 

// .m file
-(IBAction)buttonClicked
{
   NSLog(@"weight %d",iweight");
}

right click of button and assign TouchUpInside to buttonClicked method.
```